# MySQL CONVERT_TZ doesn't work for 2 same conversions

Tags: mysql, timezone, convert-tz

I got a table with event time logs, and I need to convert 2 columns to a common timezone.

So if I do (convert to different timezones)

```
        SELECT id
            ,CONVERT_TZ(starting_time, 'UTC', 'Europe/London') AS starting_time
            ,CONVERT_TZ(finishing_time, 'UTC', 'Europe/Madrid') AS finishing_time
        FROM table
```

I got all the times, but if I run

```
        SELECT id
            ,CONVERT_TZ(starting_time, 'UTC', 'Europe/London') AS starting_time
            ,CONVERT_TZ(finishing_time, 'UTC', 'Europe/London') AS finishing_time
        FROM table
```

All the time data gets `NULL`.

I loaded my TZ data with the information here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time-zone-support.html from /usr/share/zoneinfo on RHEL 5 using MySQL 5.1.63.

Comment: What are the actual values? Could you reproduce it on sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

This will happen if you haven't loaded the time zone table into `MySQL`. Try this (in console of RHEL):

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

**EDIT:** You only need to load table once. It loads the information into a table into `MySQL`, which is used from then on.

**EDIT2**: Named time zones can be used only if the time zone information tables in the `MySQL` database have been **created and populated**.

The `MySQL` installation procedure creates the time zone tables in the MySQL database, **but does not load them**.

See the version 5.1.x [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html) for details.